# Link in Dropdown Menu HTML Coding Not Working

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, dropdown

I am making a website for myself using HTML and CSS on textedit. I've managed to get the links to work for the main navigation menu headings, but the links won't work in the dropdown options. For example, when I click "Year 7" under the heading "Science" this message comes up: "No file exists at the address "Users/Mike/Documents/Practise/Navigation Page/â€œfile:///Users/Mike/Documents/Practise/Science/Year 7/ScienceYear7.htmâ€".

If I write the address as: "file:///Users/Mike/Documents/Practise/Science/Year 7/ScienceYear7.htm" it works. That is how I wrote it in the coding, yet it still doesn't seem to work.

This is the coding for that section:

```
     <li><a href=“file:///Users/Mike/Documents/Practise/Science/Science/Science.htm”>Science</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href=“file:///Users/Mike/Documents/Practise/Science/Year%207/ScienceYear7.htm”>Year 7</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Year 8</a></li>
               <li><a href=“#”>Year 9</a></li>
               <li><a href=“#”>Year 10</a></li>
               <li><a href=“#”>Year 11</a></li>
               <li><a href=“#”>Year 12</a></li>

            </ul>
```

Please help :(

Update: Both links are now not working.

Comment: Please post the code here instead of posting a screenshot of it. Most users won't open an external link.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is comming from the chars : “ ” that you are using. They are not the same as this : ".

Comment: Oh yeah!! thanks. But it seems to be autocorrecting it :/ how do I stop that??

Comment: I guess it's probably comming from the Text Editor you are using. See if you have the same problem with editors like Notepad++ or Sublime Text